# WSO2 Username test011 is not valid. User name must be a non null string

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We trying add new user to AD by using **ReadWriteLdapuserStore** as secondary.

Store in WSO2 identity server but we get error message.

[image]

> **Could not add user devdc.sure.com.sa/user123. Error is: Username user123 is not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, null**

In claim I mapped user name as following :

[image]

and my log debug is :

Caused by:

```
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Username user123 is not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, null
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1535)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1450)
    ... 85 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-28 09:33:31,691] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  Username user123 is not valid. 
User name must be a non null string with following format, null 
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminStub.addUser(UserAdminStub.java:2202)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient.addUser(UserAdminClient.java:94)
    at org.apache.jsp.user.add_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(add_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:152)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you change the username regex in user-mgt.xml file?

Comment: dear this is the username regex of my second store AD :

**<Property name="UserNameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>**

 but i think the problem not from the username regex because with the same config for roles regex, we can add roles to second store successfully

**<Property name="RoleNameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="RoleNameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>**

Answer (score 1):

The property name for username regex in secondary store AD should be **UsernameJavaRegEx** and NOT **UserNameJavaRegEx**. This is the same for username javaScript regex as well. It should be **UsernameJavaScriptRegEx**.

```
<Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
<Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
```

There was a bug in IS 5.0.0, when saving the UsernameJavaRegEx and UsernameJavaScriptRegEx from the UI for LDAP and AD, it is saved as UserNameJavaRegEx and UserNameJavaScriptRegEx. But they are read as UsernameJavaRegEx and UsernameJavaScriptRegEx. However, this was fixed in later versions. [1]

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3780